# Django: Validate DateTimeField based on another DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models

I'd like to validate a `DateTimeField` based on another `DateTimeField` in the same mode, like so:

```
class Operation(models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(start)
        ]
    )
```

I get a `TypeError` exception when POSTing:

> *'<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'DateTimeField'*

These are the variables:

> a
> datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 10, 0, 25, 29, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='America/Sao_Paulo'))
>
> b
> <django.db.models.fields.DateTimeField: start>
>
> self   <django.core.validators.MinValueValidator object at 0x104ded4d0>

I suppose I need to extract the `datetime.datetime` from the field, but I can't seem to do it from inside the model validator.

Any tips? Thank you.

Comment: Model's `clean` method is what you need, not a field validator, as ut gives you access to the  model's fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Validators cannot compare between multiple fields. In your code, `start` in `MinValueValidator(start)` represents the entire field, not the actual value of an individual instance.

You need [Model.clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)

```py
class Operation(models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        if self.start and self.end:
            if self.start > self.end:
                raise ValidationError("End datetime must be greater than start datetime.")
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's why I answered my own question almost immediately after asking. It is funny how we search for an answer for an hour, only to find it a minute after asking. it is always like that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, stupid me trying things after midnight. Anyway, I just used `clean` and it worked.